# Android Studio - Many Button Presses Cause App to Crash

Tags: android, android-studio, button, crash

So I made a program that would make a sound effect after pressing a button. However after around 30+ button presses, the app would crash and close. Is there a reason for this and how can I fix this?

Comment: Possibly you don't release audio after every play. Please add your code and stack trace

Comment: Try playing sound with Sound Pool Implementation.